# How to get date type format?

Tags: r, lubridate

I have a date in yyyymmdd format dataframe

ex.

```
df= data.frame(dat = seq.Date(from= as.Date("2021-01-01") , to = as.Date("2021-01-07"), by =1))
```

I want to create a column of strings in this format:

**example** : 2021-01-07 should look like 07-JAN-21

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want to create a column of strings in that format or do you want to change the default print format of the "Date" object?

Comment: Yes, I want to create a column of string in specified format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
toupper(format(date_column, "%d-%b-%y"))
```

here is the premise

```
> df$dat <- toupper(format(df$dat, "%d-%b-%y"))
> df
        dat
1 01-JAN-21
2 01-FEB-21
3 01-MAR-21
4 01-APR-21
5 01-MAY-21
6 01-JUN-21
7 01-JUL-21
```